# Configuring IPtables for PHP-FPM

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, iptables, php

So I have a CentOS server with Nginx and now want to run Nginx with PHP-FPM. By default it's configured to port 9000 but I'm going to use 9001. I need to know how to open port 9001 for loopback in my iptables. Which of the following are correct, are they the same, or both wrong? Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.0 --dport 9001 -j ACCEPT

or

iptables -A INPUT -i lo --dport 9001 -j ACCEPT

Comment: do you mean 127.0.0.1 ? (localhost)

Comment: If you are running PHP-FPM on the same host as nginx, might want to consider a unix socket.  Apparently it has less overhead than a tcp and just as easy to configure.

Answer (score 11):

You shouldn't need to open the firewall to connect to localhost, as it shouldn't be firewalled anyway (as a general rule).

But I would suggest following the above advice to use sockets instead.

Edit /etc/php5/fpm/php5-fpm.conf and search for these two lines:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Comment out the port one and uncomment the sock one - restart php-fpm :)

Comment: Yeah, after doing some more research I concluded that a socket would be best. Thank you very much for the how-to though :)

Comment: I guess you want to use PHP accelerator APC, this is why you want to use listen = 127.0.0.1:9000 instead. I tried the same thing without any success so far. if I got any solution, I will post it here...